# Android :voice recognition service

Tags: android, service, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

[possibly duplicate] But I didn't find answers to my questions below.

Is it possible to run voice recognition as a service? 
I would like to implement something like this: I need to call a number though my phone through voice recognition is in sleep mode.
Is there any sensor to detect the voice apart from the voice recognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with Voice Recognition, and i think it's impossible to run voice recognition as a service. Because of:

1. Problem Performance : to run as service you must call Voice Recognizer continous.
2. Don't have API Supports: to run as service you must use Service and call Voice Recognizer continous.

So, find other solution instead Voice Recognition.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Please give me a solution

Comment: I need to develop an application that will automatically call emergency number, when I say "HELP" no matter where I am. I could be inside a bus, market or somewhere

Comment: Instead of Using Service, create an user interface with a button when you want to say any thing -->tap to button and say what you want.

Comment: This link is very useful with you (upvote if it helped you): http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-android-voice-recognition/

Comment: Thank you - N-7, i will try that one